# Amazon Elastic Map Reduce : Listing job flows in command line tools Issue?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, cloudera, elastic-map-reduce, ganglia

I'm new to Amazon web services, I'm trying to run job flows on Amazon elastic map reduce jobs using command line interface tools.

I followed the steps from amazon developer guide of this developer guide from aws.But things are not getting clear to me.

If I execute the command **./elastic-mapreduce --list**
 to list the job flows. Shows the Following error.

```
/home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/amazon/coral/httpdestinationhandler.rb:23: warning: else without rescue is useless
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/amazon/coral/httpdestinationhandler.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
/home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/amazon/coral/httpdestinationhandler.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/amazon/coral/awsquery.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/amazon/coral/service.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/amazon/coral/elasticmapreduceclient.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/client.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/commands.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/pdurai/Applications/elastic-mapreduce-cli/elastic-mapreduce-cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from ./elastic-mapreduce:6:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in Advance, and Can anyone Please tell me Why i am getting the above error while listing the job flows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the avilable rvm, by using the following command

```
   $ rvm list
```

it will show:

```
   ruby-1.8.7-p374
   ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

then you should specifiy the rvm version, by using the following command

```
   $ rvm use 1.8.7
```

then you can try to list the jobflows . . .

Answer (score 2):

If `rvm` doesn't work for you, you can try changing the `Current` symbolic link:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions
sudo rm Current
sudo ln -s 1.8 Current
```

You may have to adjust the 3rd parameter to point to the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend learning how to do the process first using the service console.

It seems that your command line tool is not able to connect correctly. Maybe this is an issue with your access_key and secret_key.

Comment: I already tried in Console and that runs fine. But I want to create and run job flows by Command Line Interface(CLI) to the automate job flows each day. Let me know can I run this command in Ruby version 1.9

Comment: I myself use the Java SDK

Answer (score 0):

as @sasikkumar answer but with rbenv

```
   $ rbenv versions
```

it will show:

```
   1.8.7-p370
   * 1.9.3-p194 (set by /PATH_NEEDED/.ruby-version)
```

(Optional) If 1.8.7-p370 doesn't appear

```
   $ rbenv install 1.8.7-p370
```

then you should specifiy the rbenv version, by using the following command

```
   $ rbenv local 1.8.7-p370
```

( `local` because it will be used on PATH_NEEDED but you can use `global` for general use)

then you can try to list the jobflows . . .